# Implementing a "manager" class responsible for creating and storing objects

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, awt

The goal of this project is to take the existing code that I have already written up and implement a "manager" class that will be responsible for creating and storing Dog objects in an array. My problem here is that I don't understand why this should need to be done, which is hindering me from understanding what I need to do/change to my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Dog {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String age;


    // Constructs fields
    public Dog(String name, String breed, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;

    }

    public String setName(String Name) {
        this.name = name;
        return name;
    }

    public String setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
        return breed;
    }

    public String setage(String age) {
        this.age = age;
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Name: " + this.name + " breed: " + this.breed + " age: " + this.age);
    }
}


public class LabFour extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public LabFour() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 1, 1));

        // Creates TextField, TextArea, and button components
        name = new JTextField();
        breed = new JTextField();
        age = new JTextField();
        JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        echoDog = new JTextArea();

        // Add TextField, TextArea, and button components to the frame
        add(new JLabel("Name: "));
        add(name);
        add(new JLabel("breed: "));
        add(breed);
        add(new JLabel("age: "));
        add(age);
        add(new JLabel("Submit Button: "));
        add(jbtSubmit);
        jbtSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        add(new JLabel("Submitted Text: "));
        add(echoDog);
        echoDog.setEditable(false);

    }

    // TextFields
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField breed;
    private JTextField age;

    // Echo TextArea
    private JTextArea echoDog;

    // Listener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

        Dog[] Dogs = new Dog[50];
        int arrayLocation = 0;

        Dog Dog1 = new Dog(name.getText(), breed.getText(),
                age.getText());
        // Checks remaining array space
        if (arrayLocation < 50) {
            Dogs[arrayLocation] = Dog1;
            ++arrayLocation;
        }
        // Echos back entered text while storing the previous text
        echoDog.setText(echoDog.getText() + "\n" + Dog1.toString());
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabFour frame = new LabFour();
        frame.setTitle("Dog Interface");
        frame.setSize(1200, 900);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: "why this should need to be done" - what do you mean by "this" here?

Comment: First, rewrite     `public String setName(String Name) {
        this.name = name;
        return name;
    }` - split into getter and setter.

Comment: What I mean is that after adding the manager class, the program should essentially do the same thing it is doing now, just in a different way. What I'm not understanding is what I need to place inside of the manager class.

Comment: well, something interesting comes up to my mind. For me, add a manager class make this program more like a MVC structure. M is your dog class which store information. V is your labfour displaying stuffs on GUI, C  should be your manager calls which controls the flows between each.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written "Manager will be responsible for creating and storing Dog objects in an array", so you need to create better list of Dog objects (so you can add and remove Dogs), add CRUD methods for this list. If you'll need an array from the list you can easily convert it later.

So put something like this

```
public class Manager {

   private List<Dog> = new ArrayList<>();

   ...

   CRUD operations here

}
```

Then you need to add UI controls to actually input information about dogs, and display a table of dogs.
So it will be panes, text inputs, buttons, etc.

Answer (score 1):

well, something interesting comes up to my mind. 
For me, add a manager class make this program more like a MVC structure. M is your dog class which store information. V is your labfour displaying stuffs on GUI, C should be your manager calls which controls the flows between each.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller